# Assigning values to object properties

Tags: c#

Is there a quicker way to do the following? Want to cut down the number of lines of code.

```
var item = new SpecialObject();
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("key1", "value1");
dictionary.Add("key2", "value2");

item.Name = "name";
item.Id = 1;
item.Dictionary = dictionary;
```

Thanks..

Comment: LOCs are a stupid unit to measure something.. Andrews solution is pretty nice and looks way better than yours. Still, regarding LOCs, you`ve won nothing. You want to be clear with your code, not short.

Comment: @fielding: It's precisely *because* LOC is not much of a measure that the OP wants their code to use fewer lines, all things being equal.

Comment: No the OP wants a clean solution (which he got) but he asks for fewer LOC. Its not about how compact it is (except for code golf) - what really matters is how easy it is to understand and how clean it looks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use object initializers:

```
var item = new SpecialObject
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "name",
    Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>{
    {    
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"}
    }
}
```

**Edit re comments:**

Or use a constructor, but i think this is less readable:

calling code:

```
var item = new SpecialObject(1, "name", new Dictionary<string, object>{
        {"key1", "value1"},
        {"key2", "value2"}
});
```

ctor:

```
public SpecialObject(int id, string name, IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.name = Name;
    this.Dictionary = dict;
}
```

Comment: Gotta love anonymous constructors!

Comment: @Richard: I agree with the sentiment, but can't you come up with a more compact way of expressing it?

Comment: @Richard you mean "object initializers"

Comment: If you can initialize the Dictionary within the constructor instead of passing a new reference every time, i'd go for a constructor. Otherwise a object initializer looks better.

Comment: @andrew yes, you are right, i've just been in Java and Objective-C for too long...it dulls the senses :D

Answer (score 0):

If you can change `SpecialObject`, you could (instead of Andrews solution, which may be better):

- introduce a factory
- introduce a builder
- use the constructor

For simple objects like that, i'd go like this:

```
var item = new SpecialObject(1, "name", new Dictionary<string, object>());
item.Dictionary.Add("key1", "value1");
item.Dictionary.Add("key2", "value2");
```

This would be a good time to ask yourself why the dictionary does not get initialized in the constructor anyway, feels weird to pass it every time i create a new SpecialObject.

Comment: All solutions presented so far suffer from the follows, yours just highlighted it to me; Exposing an IDictionary on your Item object is a bad idea, because it allows objects outside of Item to manipulate it (as above). This is bad OO/encapsulation

Comment: Of course, there is just no encapsulation at all. The dictionary should be at least read-only. But i dont think this thread is about design, this is about syntax.